# Passing request.user to a queryset in ModelChoiceFilter

Tags: django, filter, modelchoicefield

I want to pass request.user to a queryset in ModelchoiceFilter, because choice entry should be limited according to login user group. I try it, but getting kwargs in filters.py did not work.

models.py

```
class Score(models.Model):
    group   = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    member  = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    date    = models.DateField()
    lane    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    score   = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

filters.py

```
class ScoreFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = {'member': ['exact'],
                'date': ['gte','lte'],
                }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        group = kwargs.pop('group', None)
        super(ScoreFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['date__gte'].label="Start Date"
        self.filters['date__lte'].label="End Date"
        self.filters['member'].queryset = Member.objects.filter(group=group)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def MemberResult(request, *args, **kwargs):
    for group in request.user.groups.filter(Q(name='mon') | Q(name='wed')):
        group = group
    s_filter = ScoreFilter(request.GET, group=group, queryset=Score.objects.filter(group=group).order_by('-date')
```

I tried many solutions related to similar questions from this site, but could not solve yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s_filter = ScoreFilter(request.GET, user=request.user, queryset=Score.objects.filter(group=group).order_by('-date')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    for group in self.user.groups.filter(Q(name='mon') | Q(name='wed')):
        group = group
    super(ScoreFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.filters['date__gte'].label="Start Date"
    self.filters['date__lte'].label="End Date"
    self.filters['member'].queryset = Member.objects.filter(group=group)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.. I corrected my question <self.fields['member'].queryset> to <self.filters['member'].queryset> though. Would you mind telling me why mine does not work?